# error loading svm learning configuration file in gate tool

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, gate, svmlight

I am new to machine learning. When I tried learning through gate, it is showing some error. The learning configuration file is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<ML-CONFIG>

<SURROUND value="false"/> 

 <FILTERING ratio='0.2' dis='far'/>

<EVALUATION method="holdout" runs="2" ratio="0.66"/>

<multiClassiﬁcation2Binary method="one-vs-anothers" thread-pool-size="2"/>

 <PARAMETER name="thresholdProbabilityBoundary" value="1.0"/> 

<PARAMETER name="thresholdProbabilityEntity" value="1.0"/> 

<PARAMETER name="thresholdProbabilityClassification" value="0.0"/>

<IS-LABEL-UPDATABLE value="true"/> 

<IS-NLPFEATURELIST-UPDATABLE value="true"/> 

 <ENGINE nickname="SVM" implementationName="SVMLibSvmJava" options = "-s 0 -t 1 -d 4 -c 5 -tau 1.2"/>


</ML-CONFIG>
```

Training attributes are inside this file. When I trained without the line containing *multiclass* xml tag it is working. when this line is added, an error is showing  like below

```
Caused by: org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 6 of document file:/home/cognicor/vagateplugin/scripts/ML_script/learningsvm: Element type "multiClassi" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

I am not aware of this thing and why it happens and seek for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `multiClassiﬁcation2Binary` string. There is a single glyph `ﬁ` that contains two joined characters "fi" together. You probably copied the text from some pdf... Simply replace `ﬁ` by `fi` and the error should go away.